# How to send form data with file upload with one Ajax call and don't use Formdata

Tags: jquery, ajax

Hi I am searching for hours for some solution, that would enable me to send normal form data from text inputs and file upload in one ajax call, but without using FormData because poor support in IE.

Is there any way how to achieve this?

Comment: Did my answer work for you user2061853?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried it by myself. But this jQuery Plugin should be able to do that:
http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload